# Collisions in Zelle graphics.py

Tags: python, python-2.7, collision-detection, shapes, zelle-graphics

I am trying to make my circle bounce off of my rectangle using Zelle graphics.py. Once the circle bounces off of the rectangle I wanted it to keep moving randomly. Here is my code so far, and it's working!
Also I know that each circle graphics technically can use the points of the smallest possible square that would fit around the circle to do the collision but I'm having trouble with doing that.

```
from graphics import *
import random

def delay(d):
    for i in range(d):
        for i in range(50):
            pass
#-------------------------------------------------
def main():


    win=GraphWin("Moving Circle",500,400)
    win.setBackground('white')
    pt= Point(100,200)
    cir=Circle(pt,30)
    #changes the color of the circle for each game
    r = random.randrange(256)
    b = random.randrange(256)
    g = random.randrange(256)
    color = color_rgb(r, g, b)
    cir.setFill(color)
    cir.draw(win)
#rectangle
    rec = Rectangle(Point(450,450), Point(275, 425))
    rec.draw(win)
    rec.setFill('black')
#-------------------------------------------------
    pt5 = Point(250,30)
    instruct1=Text(pt5, "click multiple times to start(rectangle can take multiple clicks to move)")
    instruct1.setTextColor('black')
    instruct1.draw(win)


#-------------------------------------------------
    p=cir.getCenter()
    p2=win.getMouse()

    dx=1
    dy=1

    keepGoing=True

    while keepGoing:
        d = 100
        delay(d)
        cir.move(dx,dy)
        p=cir.getCenter()
        p2=win.checkMouse()
        instruct1.setText("")


#rectanlge
        isClicked= win.checkMouse()
        if isClicked:
            rp = isClicked
            rc = rec.getCenter()
            rdx = rp.getX() - rc.getX()
            rdy = rp.getY() - rc.getY()
            rec.move(rdx,rdy)

#circle
        if((p.getX()-30)<=0.0) or ((p.getX()+30)>=500):
            dx= -dx

        if((p.getY()-30)<=0.0) or ((p.getY()+30)>=400):
            dy=-dy
        p3=win.checkMouse()



main()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I know that each circle graphics technically can use the points of the
>   smallest possible square that would fir around the circle to do the
>   collision

I'm playing with an alternate idea -- we could consider a circle around the rectangle instead of a square around the circle.  The issue for me is that we not only need to detect collision, but come out with a sense of which way to move away from the other object.  It's not just `True` and `False` but rather a `(dx, dy)` type of result.

Obviously, a circle around the rectangle is too crude, but suppose it were lots of smaller circles making up the rectangle and we measure circle center to center distance to detect a hit:

[image]

A hit on just a central (green) rectangle circle means reverse the vertical direction of the big circle.  A hit on just the end (red) circle means reverse the horizontal direction of the big circle.  And we can detect both kinds of hits and reverse the big circle completely.

Here's my rework of your code with the above in mind -- I also fixed your multiple clicking issue and made lots of style changes:

```
from random import randrange
from graphics import *

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 400

RADIUS = 30

def delay(d):
    for _ in range(d):
        for _ in range(50):
            pass

def distance(p1, p2):
    return ((p2.getX() - p1.getX()) ** 2 + (p2.getY() - p1.getY()) ** 2) ** 0.5

def intersects(circle, rectangle):

    dx, dy = 1, 1  # no change

    center = circle.getCenter()

    rectangle_radius = (rectangle.p2.getY() - rectangle.p1.getY()) / 2
    rectangle_width = rectangle.p2.getX() - rectangle.p1.getX()

    y = rectangle.getCenter().getY()

    for x in range(int(rectangle_radius * 2), int(rectangle_width - rectangle_radius * 2) + 1, int(rectangle_radius)):
        if distance(center, Point(rectangle.p1.getX() + x, y)) <= rectangle_radius + RADIUS:
            dy = -dy  # reverse vertical
            break

    if distance(center, Point(rectangle.p1.getX() + rectangle_radius, y)) <= rectangle_radius + RADIUS:
            dx = -dx  # reverse horizontal
    elif distance(center, Point(rectangle.p2.getX() - rectangle_radius, y)) <= rectangle_radius + RADIUS:
            dx = -dx  # reverse horizontal

    return (dx, dy)

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Moving Circle", WIDTH, HEIGHT)

    circle = Circle(Point(WIDTH / 5, HEIGHT / 2), RADIUS)

    # change the color of the circle for each game
    color = color_rgb(randrange(256), randrange(256), randrange(256))
    circle.setFill(color)

    circle.draw(win)

    # rectangle
    rectangle = Rectangle(Point(275, 425), Point(450, 450))  # off screen
    rectangle.setFill('black')
    rectangle.draw(win)

    dx, dy = 1, 1

    while True:
        delay(100)
        circle.move(dx, dy)

        # rectangle
        isClicked = win.checkMouse()

        if isClicked:
            point = isClicked
            center = rectangle.getCenter()
            rectangle.move(point.getX() - center.getX(), point.getY() - center.getY())

        # circle
        center = circle.getCenter()

        if (center.getX() - RADIUS) <= 0.0 or (center.getX() + RADIUS) >= WIDTH:
            dx = -dx

        if (center.getY() - RADIUS) <= 0.0 or (center.getY() + RADIUS) >= HEIGHT:
            dy = -dy

        # collision bounce

        x, y = intersects(circle, rectangle)
        dx *= x
        dy *= y

main()
```

Not perfect, but something to play around with, possibly plugging in a better `intersects()` implementation.

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!